# FineUploader Azure fails on chunking

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, fine-uploader

I'm working on a project that requires uploading large files (usually 1-10GB and maybe multiple files) to an Azure blob storage.

The fine uploader is working when chunking is not enabled, but obviously it's not ideal to upload large files like this. Though when chunking is enable each block succeeds to upload, but the blocklist fails.

[image: Error output with chunking enabled]

I'm not sure what could could be causing this, since this is handled by FineUploader.
Here is the code I have.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    button = document.getElementById('#file-picker-button');

    uploader = new qq.azure.FineUploaderBasic({
        debug: true,
        button: button,
        chunking: {
            mandatory: true,
            enabled: true,
            minFileSize: 1,
            partsize: 4000000,
            concurrent: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        retry: {
            enableAuto: true,
            maxAutoAttempts: 1
        },
        cors: {
            expected: true
        },
        request: {
            endpoint: 'https://{{ ACCOUNT_NAME }}.blob.core.windows.net/{{ BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME }}',
            containerUrl: 'https://{{ ACCOUNT_NAME }}.blob.core.windows.net/{{ BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME }}'
        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: '/shared-access-signature'
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: '/success',
            params: {
                dir_name: '{{ trip_name }}'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[image: Response headers and request payload]

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the block list sent to Storage?

Comment: Added the response/request

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was not with FineUploader, but our server.

I can add more detail when I find out what that is.